# How to write structural inductions proofs using LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode, packages

Just wondering what packages or methods I can use in LaTeX to write out a structural induction proof for a list in LaTeX; I am writing the proof out in overleaf.

As an example, I tried to write out this lemma for my proof:

```
$$(\dagger) \forall xs \forall ys. length(xs ++ ys) = length (ys ++ xs)$$
```

but this is not visually clear and I would like something that looks similar to the equation that is shown in the image below

[image: equation for list induction].

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Are you using `PlainTeX`?

Comment: If you are using LaTeX, as you say, you shouldn't use `$$` for display maths. Whatever you're using, please post a small but compilable example showing what you've tried and explain what exactly you want to do. Unless you only want answers from people versed in your field (who may mean nobody at all), you shouldn't assume we know what a structural induction proof is or how it should be typeset. Guessing you're looking for `amsmath`'s multiline display environments, but that's little more than pure speculation.